# destroy function in resource controller not working properly in LARAVEL 9

Tags: php, database, eloquent, laravel-9

when ever I delete a user from my records the wrong user gets deleted

the deletion is happening in an incremented way no matter what the user **id** I'm choosing to delete

let's say I'm deleting the user with the **id 4**

the one that actually gets deleted is the one with the **id 1**

if I try again to delete **id 4** the user with the **id of 2** gets deleted and so on.

**my view is :**

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="m-0">{{ __('Admin panel') }}</h1>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"></h5>

                            <p class="card-text">


                                @if (Session::has('successMsg'))
                                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                                        <h6 style=" text-align:center !important;"><b>Successfully Deleted! </b></h6>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                                <a class="btn btn-primary m-2" href="/addAppointment">Add new Appointment</a>
                                <a href="/appointments" class="btn btn-primary"> Appointments List</a>
                            <div class="container">
                                @if ($users->count())
                                    <table class="table" id="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Id</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>View</th>
                                                <th>Delete</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                                @if ($user->id > 1)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                                        <td><a href="/cpanel/{{ $user->id }}"
                                                                class="btn">&#128065;</a></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <form action="/cpanel/{{ $user->id }}" method="POST"
                                                                id="EditForm">
                                                                @method('DELETE')
                                                                @csrf
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                                    title='Delete' onclick="submitResult(event)"
                                                                    aria-hidden="true">&#128465;</button>
                                                            </form>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->
@endsection


@section('scripts')
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitResult(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Deleted!',
                        'Your file has been deleted.',
                        'success'
                    )
                    document.getElementById("EditForm").submit();
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
@endsection

@section('styles')
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.10.1/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
@endsection
```

**my destroy function in the user controller is:**

```php
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('login');
        } elseif (Gate::denies('cpanel')) {
            abort(403, 'action not allowed!');
        } else {
            User::destroy($id);
            return redirect('cpanel')->with('successMsg', 'User Deleted !');
        }
    }
```

**my route is:**

```php
Route::resource('/cpanel', UserController::class)->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

what Am I missing?

**EDIT:**

it seems that the **onclick="submitResult(event)"**

is causing some problem, when I remove the onclick event

the id gets sent correctly to the destroy function.

can you please Help fix this.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you check which ID is used within your `destroy`  method?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes I have checked dear sir when i dd($id) in my destroy function it doesn't show the correct id

Comment: when i use the browser's inspect i get for each user the correct id, but when i submit i get the wrong id, can you please help dear sir @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0):

i think this was probably an error caused by me.

the problem is fixed after I changed the

```
onclick="submitResult(event)"
```

to

```
onclick="submitResult(e)"
```

the `id` is now being sent correctly to the destroy function.

problem fixed.